# How should I choose my Content Manager environment ID?

Tags: web8, topology-manager

When installing the Content Manager for Web 8, you are asked to enter the Content Manager environment ID. This appears to default to Tridion_cm followed by the domain name of your database server (with punctuation removed).

Perhaps this isn't really very important and the generated default is fine, but I'm interested in what might be good practice for choosing a meaningful name. For example, does it help to keep it short? Should I refer to my DTAP environment in the name?

Comment: In the context of Topology Manager you might script the names, so I suspect you might have these configured _somewhere_. I think the names should make sense in PowerShell but also something you (or the admins for the environment) could easily troubleshoot and recognize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing that really matters is that all CM Servers that are part of a logical CM Environment use the same CM Environment ID (makes sense, right?).

That is why by default the CM Environment ID is derived from the CM DB name/server (which is common for all CM servers in the same logical environment). Peter's suggestion to use the CM server name is risky; it is fine if you don't intend to scale out your CM environment.

In a DTAP setup, each of the four logical environments is expected to have its own Topology Manager, so there is not really a need to distinguish the D,T,A and P environments in their CM env ID, but in practice it may be useful to do so (so you can easily see which environment you're managing in Topology Manager).

Comment: Great answer! I don't know how many people actually scale out their CM environments, but it makes sense that the default ID prepares you for it.

Comment: >> I don't know how many people actually scale out their CM environments - In my experience in PS, this would be "100% of the customers I worked at had at least 2 CM servers in production - in some cases over 20."

Answer (score 4):

I think it's actually `DatabaseName_DatabaseMachineName`

I don't think it matters but DEV or similar might be more straightforward.

You're going to be typing it so I guess shorter the better?

Comment: We default to this since its the most likely to be unique across DTAP, and a somewhat safe bet as default. Of course, change it as much as you need to. In the end, it should make sense to YOU.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the actual machine name of the Content Manager machine. Using the database server name is equally valid, but I just prefer to refer to the actual machine that the CM runs on.